# Databinding dynamic value using $= does not work on "class" attribute

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a problem with the $= operator.

I've got a component I've created, call it "somecomponent". This component works just fine but I want to add a class to help me customize some stuff. This class will be fetch from a datasource.

I create a property like this:

```
properties: {
    somevar: {
        type: String,
        readOnly: true
    },
...
```

I pass the value while creating my component in my webpage as such:

```
<somecomponent somevar="<?= $datasource['somevar'] ?>"></somecomponent>
```

and use it in my

```
<div class$="{{somevar}}"></div>
```

When I look in the Google Chrome inspector, I see the

```
<somecomponent somevar="somevalue"></somecomponent>
```

But in the div, I always see

```
<div class="style-scope somecomponent"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to turn off shady dom and use shadow dom instead. I think you're referencing the wrong div here and seeing one of shady dom's effects.

Comment: Just find out that the readOnly attribute should not be there at the first place. Removed it and work perfectly.